# Same MDX, different result on jasperreports 4.0 and Schema Workbench and Jasperserver 3.7.1

Tags: jasper-reports, mdx, jasperserver

I'm using jasperserver 3.7.1 and this week i  upgraded to jasperreports 4.0
Everything went fine until i realize that jasperreports does not show any data for this year (2011).
This is strange because if i went to Schema workbench or jasperserver 3.7.1 my MDX query give the expected result.
Every MDX query for the year 2011 is showing empty results.

This is an MDX simple example:

```
  select {[Measures].[Ocorrencias]} ON COLUMNS,
  { [Time.month].[2011].[Q1].Children } ON ROWS
  from [Ocorrencias]
```

This is the time dimension of my shcema:

```
<Dimension type="TimeDimension" name="Time">
    <Hierarchy name="month" hasAll="true" primaryKey="idtempo">
      <Table name="timeid">
      </Table>
      <Level name="Ano" column="ano" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Trimestre" column="idtrimestre" nameColumn="trimestre" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Mes" column="idmes" nameColumn="mes" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="week" hasAll="true" primaryKey="idtempo">
      <Table name="timeid">
      </Table>
      <Level name="Ano" column="ano" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Semana" column="semana_ano" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeWeeks" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Dia" column="dia_mes" nameColumn="dia_nome" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
```

[This is](http://pastebin.com/QGz2jAf2) the whole schema file.

I already have done a clean installation and the problem persists.

If you can help me or point in any direction, i really apreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that if i change 2011 to 2010, i have the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I only post here this answer to help other people who commit the same mistake.

The problem is that my time database table have some mistakes on the columnn days, that i didn't notice before.
For unkown reason the old mondrian work with that mistake.